# Access a buildConfigField inside another gradle file

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I need to access a `buildConfigField` value from my apps `build.gradle` into another `Gradle` file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        buildConfigField "String", "Version", "\"${getVersion()}\""
    }
}
```

Using another `Gradle` file as

```
println("Version info"+ android.defaultConfig.buildConfigField.getVersion())
```

But getting an error

Could not get unknown property 'buildConfigField'

Comment: No you can't access **buildConfigField** directly like that. It's used by Gradle to create auto-generated `BuildConfig` class. Why don't you directly use that `getVersion()` method in your another gradle file?

Comment: Cannot use it directly in the other gradle file it gives me this error Could not find method getVersion() for arguments [] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Answer (score 2):

This Worked for me

```
println("Version info" + android.defaultConfig.buildConfigFields["Version"].value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can access the `defualtConfig` like below:

```
def value = defaultConfig.buildConfigFields.Version.value
println(value)
```